# How to pass arguments to remote script from nodejs file using ssh-exec?

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh

Hi i want to execute a bash script on remote machine from a nodejs file. I am using ssh-exec function. This allow me to run remote script easily but when i need to pass some arguments to it, there comes the real problem because the current syntax is passing the arguments as string instead of their values.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var exec=require('ssh-exec');
var arg1="abc";
var arg2="def";
var arg3="ghd";
exec('"./test.sh" arg1 arg2 arg3' ,
  {user:'ubuntu',host:'a.b.c.d'}, function(err, stdout) {
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
  console.log(stdout);
 console.log('success');
});    `
```

Comment: What do you mean, so `arg1` is processed as `"arg1"` and not `"abc"`?

Comment: Looking at the code highlighting in the question it's kinda obvious. You need to compose a string using the variables you declared earlier. `"./test.sh " + arg1 + " " + arg2 + " " + arg3` When you googled for a solution prior to posting here, you probably got hung up on nodejs, SSH, etc. All you need to look up is string composition though. The first google result for "js string composition" is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Yes that is basic javascript. I recommend you to start learning javascript by reading books, or watching online free video tutorials.

Comment: Thanks alot Chris G for suggesting this solution because i was not getting answer to this from google and npm documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You must concatenate your variables into the string of the command ; otherwise you are just adding the variables' names to the command. See below :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var exec = require('ssh-exec');
var arg1 = "abc";
var arg2 = "def";
var arg3 = "ghd";
exec(`"./test.sh" ${arg1} ${arg2} ${arg3}` {
    user: 'ubuntu',
    host: 'a.b.c.d'
}, function(err, stdout) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log('success');
});
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are this easy and are already answered.

Comment: What's wrong with helping people who have easy questions ? It's not because the guy is a beginner that he should't be able to get help.